# Checks if user is part of Active Directory group

Tags: c#, mvc, active-directory

I'm working in C# using PrincipalContext to do a check if user is part of security group for access to the site. Site is asp.net MVC and part of an internal network with security groups set up via active directory.

Currently load times for pages are about 2.5-3 seconds on first load and then about 1.4-1.5 seconds on subsequent loads for each action. I'd like to decrease the time if possible and have set the query to check the domain of the user which cut some time out.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var alias = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    var domain = alias.Substring(0, alias.IndexOf("\\"));
    alias = alias.Substring(alias.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
    var accessLevel = this.Roles;

    if (CheckAccess(accessLevel, alias, domain))
    {
        return;
    }
}

private bool CheckAccess(string group, string user, string userDomain)
{
    PrincipalContext ctx;
    GroupPrincipal AdGroup = null;
    UserPrincipal AdUser = null;
    using (Forest forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest())
    {
        foreach(Domain domain in forest.Domains)
        {
            if (domain.Name.Contains("domain1"))
            {
                ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, "username", "password");
                if (group == "WRITE")
                {
                    AdGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "group1");
                }

                if (userDomain.ToLower().Contains("domain1"))
                {
                    AdUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);
                }
            }
            else if (domain.Name.Contains("domain2"))
            {
                if (userDomain.ToLower().Contains("domain2"))
                {
                    ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, "username", "password");
                    AdUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);
                }
            }
        }

        if (AdGroup != null && AdUser != null)
        {
            if (AdUser.IsMemberOf(AdGroup))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
               return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
     }
}
```

Also first question on CodeReview, let me know if there is anything to do to improve the question that I might have missed in the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OnAuthorization()**

If the possibility exists that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` dosn't contain `\` the call to `alias.Substring()` will fail. Instead of calling two times `alias.IndexOf("\\")` you could use `string.Split()`.

This

```
if (CheckAccess(accessLevel, alias, domain))
{
    return;
}
```

is a little bit useless. You don't rellay care about the returned value of `CheckAccess()` hence you could remove it. But I guess thats not what you want. Instead you should e.g throw an [`AuthenticationException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.authenticationexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

**CheckAccess**

`PrincipalContext`, `GroupPrincipal` and `UserPrincipal` are implementing the `IDisposable` interface, hence its best practice to enclose the usage in a `using` block.

Local variables should, based on the .NET Naming Guidelines, be named using `camelCase` casing and shouldn't use abbreviations. Hence `AdUser` should be `activeDirectoryUser` and `AdGroup` should be `activeDirectoryGroup`.

You should validate `group` and `userDomain` wether you really need to do the loop and you could store the result in a `bool` as well like so

```
bool userDomainIsInDomain1 = userDomain.ToLower().Contains("domain1");
bool userDomainIsInDomain2 = userDomain.ToLower().Contains("domain2");
bool groupCanWrite = group == "WRITE";  

if(!userDomainIsInDomain && !userDomainIsInDomain2 && !groupCanWrite)
{ 
    return false;
}
```

We can now use the introduced `bool` variables in the loop like so

```
foreach (Domain domain in forest.Domains)
{
    if (domain.Name.Contains("domain1"))
    {
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, "username", "password"))
        {
            if (groupCanWrite)
            {
                activeDirectoryGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "group1");
            }

            if (userDomainIsInDomain1)
            {
                activeDirectoryUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (domain.Name.Contains("domain2"))
    {
        if (userDomainIsInDomain2)
        {
            using(var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, "username", "password"))
            {
                activeDirectoryUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but wait we can do better than that. We should extract two methods, one to get the `UserPrincipal` and one to get the `GroupPrincipal`.

```
private UserPrincipal FetchUserPrincipal(string domainName, string userName, string password, string user)  
{
    using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, userName, password))
    {
        return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, user);
    }
}
```

I am unsure about the `user` variable because I don't know if `user` is the same as `"username"`.

```
private GroupPrincipal FetchGroupPrincipal(string domainName, string userName, string password, string groupName)  
{
    using (var principalContext= new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer, userName, password))
    {
        return GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, groupName);
    }
}
```

After implementing these methods the former `CheckAccess()` method will look like this

```
private bool CheckAccess(string group, string user, string userDomain)
{
    bool userDomainIsInDomain1 = userDomain.ToLower().Contains("domain1");
    bool userDomainIsInDomain2 = userDomain.ToLower().Contains("domain2");
    bool groupCanWrite = group == "WRITE";  
    
    if(!userDomainIsInDomain && !userDomainIsInDomain2 && !groupCanWrite)
    { 
        return false;
    }  

    GroupPrincipal activeDirectoryGroup = null;
    UserPrincipal activeDirectoryUser = null;
    using (Forest forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest())
    {
        foreach (Domain domain in forest.Domains)
        {
            if (domain.Name.Contains("domain1"))
            {
                if (groupCanWrite)
                {
                    activeDirectoryGroup = FetchGroupPrincipal(domain.Name, "username", "password", "group1"); 
                }

                if (userDomainIsInDomain1)
                {
                    activeDirectoryUser = FetchUserPrincipal(domain.Name, "username", "password", user); 
                }
            }
            else if (userDomainIsInDomain2 && domain.Name.Contains("domain2"))
            {
                activeDirectoryUser = FetchUserPrincipal(domain.Name, "username", "password", user); 
            }
        }  

        if (AdGroup != null && AdUser != null)
        {
            return AdUser.IsMemberOf(AdGroup);
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```

As you can see, I have simplified the `if..else` at the bottom as well.

Comment: I'd use https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/648075 instead of `.ToLower().Contains();`. Make it an extension method and you can easily reuse it everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! Kinda shocked how bad my logic was. The return on the onAuthorization was something I was seeing on tutorials for custom Authorization attributes. I'm gonna test to see if it works as intended if that isn't there.

Comment: Found an issue with the solution when calling IsMemberOf. It leverages the PrincipalContext used in the group and user so you can't dispose of them until after that call.

Comment: I can't help but notice, that your `using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(...` somewhat contradicts that "based on the .NET Naming Guidelines variables should be named using camelCase casing and shouldn't use abbreviations" as you mentioned earlier ;-)

Comment: @KrzysztofJabłoński good catch, fixed ;-)